# containerless statements of knockoutjs is not working in hottowel SPA?

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js, breeze, durandal, hottowel

I was trying to use the containerless statements like `<!--ko if:IsShowData==true -->` of knockoutjs in hot towel template but it was not woring instead if i use visible binding with some element like div then it work very fine.(`<div data-bind="visible: IsShowData==true"></div>`)

Can anybody tell me if containerless statements of knockoutjs doesnt work in hot towel template?

In Default Hot towel template i added few lines in home.html and home.js as follow:

```
views/home.html

<section>
    <h2 class="page-title" data-bind="text: title"></h2>
</section>

<!-- ko if: active()==true -->
hiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
<!--/ko-->


<div data-bind="visible: active() == true">
    byeeeeeeeeeeeee
</div>
```

And In viewmodels/home.js file

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        active:ko.observable(false),
        title: 'Home View'
    };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        logger.log('Home View Activated', null, 'home', true);
        return true;
    }
    //#endregion
});
```

i will see hiiiiiiii but i will not see byeeeeee

Comment: The containerless bindings should just work. Please post some mroe code how is your view and viewmodel look like!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is not related to Knockout or to the `if` contenerless binding but Durandal.js (which is used by the HotTowel templates) and how Durandal handles the view model.

Because in Durandal.js your **viewmodel should only contain one root element** and it removes the root level comments.

From the [documentation](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-View/):

> The view has exactly one root element. Durandal requires this. *If
>   comments are found at the root, they will be removed.* In the case
>   where more than one root element is found, they will be wrapped in a
>   div.

So the solution is simple: just more the two text inside the `section` or wrap everything into a `div` or `section`:

```
<section>
    <h2 class="page-title" data-bind="text: title"></h2>

    <!-- ko if: active()==true -->
         hiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
    <!--/ko-->


    <div data-bind="visible: active() == true">
         byeeeeeeeeeeeee
   </div>
</section>
```

Or

```
<div>
     <section>
        <h2 class="page-title" data-bind="text: title"></h2>
     </section>

    <!-- ko if: active()==true -->
       hiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
    <!--/ko-->


     <div data-bind="visible: active() == true">
        byeeeeeeeeeeeee
    </div>
</div>
```

By the way instead of `if: active()==true` and `visible: active() == true` you can simple write: `if: active` and `visible: active`

Comment: some mobile browsers and minification tools also remove html comments (not all). in those caes, ko containerless bindings will get stripped.

Comment: Hmm haven't ran into this but looking this up it appears to be the service provider stripping comments, not the browser itself.  If that is incorrect which browsers have you seen?