# Knockout containerless 'with' binding not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

This containerless `with` binding doesn't set the bindingContext as I would expect; it's still set to the containing parent of ladder.

```
<!-- ko with:ladder -->
<table>
    //Context here is the $root object, not $root.ladder
    //some foreach binding here
</table>

<a  href="#" data-bind="click: addPages">Add 4 pages</a>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This containerful method works fine though.

```
<table class="ladder-table" data-bind="with:ladder">
    //the context is correctly set to ladder in this instance
    //some foreach binding here
</table>
<br />
<a  href="#" data-bind="click: ladder.addPages">Add 4 pages</a>
```

Anyone know what's up with that?  Google didn't give any results.

Comment: Can you check that the ko comments are still in the source when its rendered in the browser? Maybe some framework what you are using or a reverse proxy, etc. stripps out your comments...

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that reproduces the problem ?

Comment: Second @nemesv, your code seems to be [working as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/NSd8H/).

Comment: Ah,  you're right @nemesv.  I'm using Durandal, and any outer comments are stripped when it does it's composition.

Comment: Then you should add this info into your question, and tag it with durandal. And for a solution just wrap your markup into `div` durandal only removes root level comments. Related/duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271248/containerless-statements-of-knockoutjs-is-not-working-in-hottowel-spa/17275094#17275094

Comment: Also if that question provides an answer you feel is suitable, consider up-voting it for future visitors to be able to find it faster, and consider closing this question.

Comment: The answer to the other one was indeed the same underlying issue,  but the fact my searching was unable to pick up that question+answer altogether says it would be better to leave this question open.  I will link to that answer though,  so more people may find it via my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with Durandal, not Knockout, as this answer explains:
[containerless statements of knockoutjs is not working in hottowel SPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271248/containerless-statements-of-knockoutjs-is-not-working-in-hottowel-spa/17275094#17275094)

In short, Durandal allows only one root element per view.

goodView.html

```
<div>
    <--ko foreach:stuff-->
      //stuff
    <--/ko-->
</div>
```

badView.html

```
<div>
   <stuff/>
</div>
<--ko foreach:stuff-->  //these elements are stripped out
  //stuff
<--/ko-->
```

Thanks @nemesv